# Why console applications are [way] bigger than GUI based programs (windows forms)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, size

I have been for a long time an all-time [visual] basic programmer. Recently I found a neat android app which teaches C++ and I downloaded it, and I have been learning this language for a few weeks now.

However, I noticed something significantly different in my EXE files. The C++ programs generated by Code::Blocks are each about 1 MB in size, yet most of my programs generated with Visual Basic 6.0 and 2010 barely ever get passed 100 KB.

One thing to note is that all of my few C++ programs are console applications, and all of my BASIC programs are GUI based apps. So my question is: **is this size gap due to the type of application, or it has to do with how C++ and BASIC programs are compiled?**

Comment: VB.NET gets compiled to insanely compact bytecode, with the .NET environment being loaded from the system where the assembly runs. Support libraries aren't compiled into the assembly. The C++ application probably statically links in all of its support libraries. You are comparing apples to oranges here.

Comment: Lets say that you will make a simple "hello world" program. The console App EXE will weigh about 1 MB, the Windows Form app will weigh about 1 KB. Nothing fancy, default compilers.

Comment: You should try to compile your C++ program with optimizations (in Release mode). Without debug info and with space optimizations executables are way smaller.

Comment: @David FYI, the executable produced by Visual Studio 2015 for a "Hello World" program is 10KB if the runtime is not linked in, 100KB with it linked in.  Nowhere near 1 MB.  This is in release mode with "Optimize for Speed" setting, so if I chose "Optimize for size" I may get a smaller file.

Comment: @Drop I'm going to look into that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That size is for VB6

Comment: @David I am giving the sizes of a "Hello World" C++ program produced by Visual Studio 2015.  I don't even have VB 6 installed on my machine.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were referring to the 1KB size, ther other one is a C++ written console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely answer is that your console program is probably being statically linked to its dependent libraries, meaning it's copying machine code from external libraries into your application's executable. Whereas the GUI application is probably linking to shared libraries which loads the dependent machine code at runtime into memory. You can inspect the shared library dependencies of your application to verify.

Comment: Yeah, just checked that and the list for the NET app is about 120 the console app is just 10. I am not accustomed to check dependencies.

Comment: There you go! You could link the console application against shared libraries and it should be much smaller.